# mysql: update or create entry where submitted date is newer than in db

Tags: mysql

as in the title said I want to either insert a new value or if its primary key already existant update the row but only if the database value is older than the given new one.

the query is something like this but it has problems with the where statement

```
INSERT INTO myTable(field1_key, field2, datefield) VALUES('val1', 'val2', '2012-12-12 12:12:12')   
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
field2='val2'
datefield='2012-12-12 12:12:12'
WHERE datefield <'2012-12-12 12:12:12'
```

Comment: Is `field1` promary key? If not, you'll never get key duplication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's newer just "replace" it with the same value:

```
INSERT INTO myTable(field1, field2, datefield) VALUES ('val1', 'val2', '2012:12:12 12:12')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
datefield=IF(datefield < VALUES(datefield), VALUES(datefield), datefield),
field2=IF(datefield < VALUES(datefield), VALUES(field2), field2)
```

Comment: doesnt work completely: the second part only updates the datefield. But it should update all fields (+ field 1). How to do this? thanks

Comment: That doesn't make sense. What is you primary key?

Comment: field1 is the primary key, my real table has more than these two rows. these rows are not updated

Comment: Then you can't ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `field1` because if a row with the value already exists it would update that row and `field1` wouldn't change and if it doesn't yet exist a row will be inserted so   the UPDATE won't be executed at all.

Comment: you're right. it should not update field field1, but it should update datefield + the others. i change my question.

Comment: i guess its something lik INSERT INTO myTable(field1, datefield) VALUES ('val1', '2012:12:12 12:12')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
datefield=IF(datefield < VALUES(datefield), VALUES(datefield), field2=IF(datefield < VALUES(datefield), VALUES(field2), field2)

Comment: there's still a problem: the fields are still not updated. fields are of type int(11). but if i test with field2=IF(datefield < VALUES(datefield), 11, 22) then its getting updated

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21219/discussion-between-andrekr-and-user1324936)